# Rspec - why did I have to require active_support in my spec file

Tags: ruby, rspec

I just started using rspec to write some unit tests.

In my spec file I had to add the line `require 'active_support/core_ext'` because one of the methods I am running the tests on uses the `blank?` method. Without it I got an error along the lines of unknown method `blank`.

The spec looks like:

```
it 'returns error if receives a string as payload' do
    expect {ensure_properties([:title], 'ABC')}.to raise_error(MyError)
end
```

And `ensure_properties` use blank like this:

```
if value.is_a? String and value.blank?
   raise_my_error('Something')
end
```

I was just wondering why does the spec file itself need to have that require. Isn't the spec just running to get the result from that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't the spec just running to get the result from that function?

More or less. But that function/method needs `blank?`. Instead of putting that require in your spec file, you could put it in the tested method's file and it'd work.

You mention Active Support. Is this a rails app? If so, the proper course of action is to load the rails env in your rails_helper/spec_helper. (unless you're not doing that on purpose, in an attempt to speed up specs or something like that).

Comment: Thanks - `load the rails env in your rails_helper/spec_helper` how do I go about doing that? Is there is a specific config key?

Comment: @userMod2: rspec should have generated proper files when you executed `rspec --init`. Create a dummy rails app, add rspec there and compare resulting files with yours. The line you need looks something like this: `require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)`

Comment: The only file I noticed it made was `spec_helper.rb` - should it go there?

Comment: @userMod2: no rails_helper, you say? Interesting. Does this spec_helper contain something similar to what I posted? What were the steps you did?

Comment: @userMod2: ah, the command you need is `rails generate rspec:install`

Comment: So that spec has no mention of anything. I simply did `rspec --init`

Comment: So I just placed that line above `require File.expand_path('../../config/application.rb', __FILE__)` at teh top of the spec_helper file. Does the trick. Thanks